# Access Non Static Method inside Static Method AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Here is my scenario: I am trying to get a value from frontend using AJAX and then want to use this in a non-static method for some calculations. But I am getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I know how to use non-static method/data members in a static method by creating obrect Reference that I did but still error is same.

Code:

```
[WebMethod]
[WebScript]
public static string refAssignments(getVal rf)
{
    string value = rf.valueFromAJAX;
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();

    string result = obj.analyse(value);
}
```

Here `Analyse()` is a non-static method all I want is to use this method inside the static method `refAssignments`.

I tried earlier questions but wasn't successful! Can someone point where I am doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SirRufo can you provide solution? I am confused in that question I have read but failed to achieve in my Scenario

Comment: Well, read the duplicate question and the answers. You try to use a reference when the reference points to null. Don't do that or ensure that you have a valid reference. Thats all

Comment: is there anyway to delete my question ? :-D i m dead what i was doing is totally NERD thing

Comment: go to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read what you can do and what you can not do here on stackoverflow. It is documented and waiting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't relevant with the `Analyse` method is non-static or not. Probably, `rf` object is null. Check the `rf` object;

```
if (rf != null)
{
    string value = rf.valueFromAJAX;
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    string result = obj.analyse(value);
}
else
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to delete my question ? :-D i m dead what i was doing is totally NERD thing